# how to add a new phone contact in android iin java with multiple contact data provided in json

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

current i am trying to make a app where the user and export his phone contacts as a json file and later he can import the json file to the app and can add all the contacts stored in the json file to his ohone contact.

I am unable to find the correct way to do this in java, any help for this is highly appreciated.

plz note a json file will contain atleast 100 contact and these 100 contacts will have to be added to the phone contact when imported. Thnks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You do this via in-built system Intent

```
Intent contactsPage = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
contactsPage.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
contactsPage.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, nameString);
contactsPage.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phoneNumberString);
```

For further information refer to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract

Comment: this method is not automatic, it requires user to click the tick mark to add contact,i need a automatic solution